# Nested for loop flow control in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

trying to write a function to compute different account balances using the compound interest formula in matlab. In this case, it needs to be able to support multiple Interest rates and number of years input. I'm currently using nested for loops, and it works fine for the first set of interest rates, but then it runs only the last number of years calculating for the second and any later values in the interest input array

```
function ans =  growth_of_money(P,I,n)

    disp(['     P     ','n     ','I    ','Total']);

 for I = I
      for n = n

          disp([P,n,I,compound_interest(P,I,n)]);

      end 

  end

end

function T = compound_interest(P,I,n)

T= P.*((1.+I).^n);

end
```

This is the output I'm getting currently:

```
 P     n     I    Total
 2     1     4    10

 2     3     4   250

       2           3           7        1024
```

What am I missing? How can I make it go back to the first value of n for the second run of I?

Comment: There are a lot of issues with your code. Don't use `ans` as a variable name (in you function output). `for I=I` is confusing, and probably not doing what you expect, check that out. `1.+I` is confusing, do you mean `1.` added to `I`, or are you doing the same thing as for element-wise multiplication `.*` for addition? That is not used, there is no separate concept of "matrix addition" like there is for matrix multiplication. Since all of your inputs to `compound_interest` are scalars, `.*` is not necessary anyway.

Comment: @David - I changed the .*, as far as the I=I, I just want it to run for the array of elements in I, so is there a better way to do that? If I just put "For I" it won't run. The 1.+I is because of the formula, it needs to add 1 to the value that is at the current element being accessed at I. Do I need to do that a different way? Sorry, I usually program in c++ (I'm a CS major), but helping out a friend in matlab

Comment: `1+I` adds 1 to `I`. Write `for ii=I` to iterate over the values in `I`, then use `ii` inside the loop which will give the elements of `I`. You can also do `for 1:numel(I)` then use `I(ii)` inside to access the elements of `I`. Just write some simple loops and get them to print out what is happening, or just look up a beginners Matlab tutorial. This stuff is pretty basic and has been covered in many places before.

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out, there are quite a few things wrong with your code. You can inspect the code below to work out how to improve your code. 
For single value inputs (e.g., one value of n, one of I).

```
function growth_of_money(P,I,n)
    T = compound_interest(P,I,n);
    fprintf(1,'P: %.1f;   N: %.1f;   I: %.1f;   Total: %.1f; \n',P,I,n,T);          
end

function T = compound_interest(P,I,n)    
    T= P.*((1.+I).^n);    
end
```

For multiple value inputs, and assuming you want to use `disp` function (which really, is not ideal), you can use something like this:

```
function growth_of_money(P,I,n)

        disp('P    N   I  Total');    
for i=I
    for k=n
        T = compound_interest(P,i,k);
        disp([P i k T]);    
    end
end

end

function T = compound_interest(P,I,n)    
    T= P.*((1.+I).^n);    
end
```